# Angular HttpClientTestingModule breaks my authentication module

Tags: angular, http

I have an app using Angular 10, and the user needs credentials to access this app.

The authentication service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { User } from "./user.model";
import * as jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private serverHostName : string = window.location.hostname;
    private serverHostPort : string = window.location.port;
    // private serverHostName : string = 'localhost';
    // private serverHostPort : string = '8080';
    private loginUrl = '//' + this.serverHostName + ':' + this.serverHostPort + '/login';
    
    userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
    private tokenExpirationTimer: any;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

    test () {
        console.log("AUTH SERVICE IS ACCESIBLE")
    }

    login (username: string, password: string) {
        return this.httpClient.post<HttpResponse<null>>(
            this.loginUrl,
            {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }, 
            {observe: 'response'}
        )
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError), 
            tap(resData => {
                let user: User;
                let authHeader = resData.headers.get('Authorization');
                console.log("TOKEN HEADER: ", authHeader);
                if (authHeader) {
                    const encodedToken = authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
                    user = this.createUserFromJWT(encodedToken) ;
                }
                // Set user as current logged user
                this.userSubject.next(user);
                // Set expiration timeout
                this.autoLogout(user.tokenExpirationDate);
                localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user));
            })
        );
    }

    autoLogin() {
        // Get user data from local storage as plain js object
        const userData: {
            username: string;
            _token: string;
            _tokenExpirationDate: string;
        } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
        if(!userData) {
            // There is no user data stored
            return;
        }

        // Construct a proper User object using the info from userData
        const loadedUser = new User(
            userData.username, 
            userData._token, 
            new Date(userData._tokenExpirationDate)
        );

        // The user.getToken() method returns null if token is invalid
        if(loadedUser.token){
            // The token is valid and we can set the user as the current logged user
            this.userSubject.next(loadedUser);
            // Set the expiration timer
            this.autoLogout(loadedUser.tokenExpirationDate);
        }
    }

    logout() {
        // Sets the user to null again
        this.userSubject.next(null);
        // Redirect to the authentication page
        this.router.navigate(['/authenticate']);
        // Clear the local storage
        localStorage.removeItem('userData');
        
        // If there is an expiration timer running, clear it
        if(this.tokenExpirationTimer){
            clearTimeout(this.tokenExpirationTimer);
        }
        this.tokenExpirationTimer = null;
    }

    autoLogout(expirationDate: Date) {
        const expirationDuration = expirationDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
        console.log("EXPIRATION DURATION:", expirationDuration);

        // If the expiration date is in the future, set a timer. Logout otherwise.
        if (expirationDuration > 0){
            this.tokenExpirationTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                this.logout();
            }, expirationDuration);
        } else {
            this.logout()
        }
    }

    private handleError(errorRes: HttpErrorResponse) {
        let errorMessage = 'An unknown error ocurred.';
        console.log("ERROR MESSAGE FORMAT: ", errorRes);

        if(!errorRes.error || !errorRes.error.error) {
            throwError(errorMessage);
        }
        switch (errorRes.error.error) {
            case 'Unauthorized':
                errorMessage = "User is unauthorized or it does not exist";
                break;
            default:
                errorMessage = errorRes.error.message;
                break;
        }
        return throwError(errorMessage);

    }

    private createUserFromJWT(encodedToken: string) : User {
        let decodedToken =  jwt_decode(encodedToken);
        console.log("DECODED TOKEN: ", decodedToken);

        let user : User;

        if (decodedToken) {
            // Date is expressed in seconds in the JWT. We need millis.
            let expDate = new Date(decodedToken.exp * 1000);
            user = new User(decodedToken.sub, encodedToken,  expDate);
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

I also have another service sending Http requests to the back end, and I used the `HttpClientTestingModule` to test it. But when I import it in my `app.module.ts`, the authentication service stops working. It does not throw any error in the console, it just hangs there forever without displaying the main page. As soon as I remove the import, everything works again.

How can the import of a testing module break my service ?

Comment: can you share your test file

Comment: The test files are not the cause of the problem. I tried to remove them, make the import in the app.module.ts file and the problem was there. The issue either comes from angular itself or from the file I posted.